# Why use of static enum?

Tags: java, enums

I was trying to find the difference between declaring an enum static?

```
public class Example {
  public static enum Days {
    MONDAY(1);

    private int day;
    private Days(int day) {
      this.day = day;
    } 

    public int getDayNum() {
      return day;
    }
  }
}
```

And the one below

```
public class Example {
  public enum Days {
    MONDAY(1);

    private int day;
    private Days(int day) {
      this.day = day;
    } 

    public int getDayNum() {
      return day;
    }
  }
}
```

I can access both of the above the exact same way

```
Example.Days.MONDAY.getDayNum();
```

This is because an enum is `static, final`. So whats the difference? When to use either of the above?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per the [JLS 8.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9):

> Nested enum types are implicitly static. It is permissible to explicitly declare a nested enum type to be static.
>
> *This implies that it is impossible to define a local (§14.3) enum, or to define an enum in an inner class (§8.1.3).*

Answer (score 4):

`Enums` are implicitly `public static final`.

So there is no difference when using static-keyword in enums.

Comment: I don't think a nested enum must be `public`.  They are `static` and nearly-`final`.  That is, `enum constants` can override methods in the `enum`.

Comment: Yes, I tried `enum Days` and tried to access it from another package, it  wouldn't work. I changed it to `public` and it was fine.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference - Java just allows redundant keywords in a lot of cases, allowing you to be explicit if you so choose.  In general, though, It's understood that enums are static, so there's no reason in my mind to declare it that way

Answer (score 1):

[**Docs says**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9)

> An enum type is **implicitly final** unless it contains at least one enum constant that has a class body.
>
> Nested enum types are **implicitly static**. It is permissable to explicitly declare a nested enum type to be static.